# WinMerge command line using powershell

Tags: powershell, winmerge

I would like to build a  PowerShell wrapper for WinMerge command that I can run that will compare snapshot  of data and display the output. I want to load a set of linefilters  but I like see the switch for /f filter is related to mask or name.

command

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge\WinMergeU.exe -ArgumentList /e /u /f "<id value="\d+[0-9]-[0-9]" />" "D:\HL7Tools\validator\DivDose\DFSP901-av.xml" "D:\HL7Tools\validator\DivDose\DF
SP902-av.xml"
```

[image]

> Is this something that can be done or is WinMerge command just something like that open WinMerge I dont see a switch for it?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you are asking, start `WinMerge /?` to see the help file.

Comment: @LotPings I have updated the post